# Save form when user refreshes page from browser or click on any anchor tag inside page

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I have made a form in drupal.

What I want is when the browser unload the page from any click whether by clicking on anchor tag or from browser refresh buttons I want to save data of my form through js/ajax or anything possible in drupal.

If any more explanation needed please do ask me. Thanks in advance.

I was trying do this by browser 'unload' event and 'beforeunload' event. But unable to save data of my form because browser doesn't wait for anything writtent inside and just ask for confirmation. Any help will appreciated.

This what I was trying to do:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
// this is actually restricting and asking for confirmation
return 'Do you really want to leave?';
```

//but coming here instead of it what i want
  //is save the form then return if user says yes and no the don't save the form.
 //but code for saving here is not working.
});

Comment: When clicking anchors it's easy to prevent the default click, save the form, and then redirect. On browser unload, it's not so easy, you can't really control when and if the user is allowed to leave your site, as that would be really annoying.

Comment: is there any other way around for this saving of form?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented above on anchor with ajax. (i.e.) I have checked if a form is edited then a alert is shown if user clicks on any anchor element. Afterwards user form is saved if user agrees else changes discarded.
For browser refresh, I didn't get any solution.
Thanks for this help and discussion.